# Divide list into two parts based on condition python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which contains a chat conversation between agent and customer.

```
chat = ['agent',
        'Hi',
        'how may I help you?',
        'customer',
        'I am facing issue with internet',
        'agent',
        'Can i know your name and mobile no.?'
        'customer',
        'john doe',
        '111111',..... ]
```

This is a sample of chat list.

I am looking to divide the list into two parts, `agent_chat` and `customer_chat`, where agent_chat contains all the lines that agent said, and customer_chat containing the lines said by customer.

Something like this(final output).

```
agent_chat = ['Hi','how may I help you?','Can i know your name and mobile no.?'...]
customer_chat = ['I am facing issue with internet','john doe','111111',...]
```

I'm facing issues while solving this, i tried using list.index() method to split the chat list based on indexes, but I'm getting multiple values for the same index.

For example, the following snippet:

```py
[chat.index(l) for l in chat if l=='agent']
```

Displays `[0, 0]`, since its only giving me first occurrence.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired output?

Comment: How do we know which lines are said by the customer and which by the agent? What if one of them sent consecutive messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my solution to your problem.

```
chat = ['agent',
        'Hi',
        'how may I help you?',
        'customer',
        'I am facing issue with internet',
        'agent',
        'Can i know your name and mobile no.?',
        'customer',
        'john doe',
        '111111']

agent_list = []
customer_list = []

agent = False
customer = False
for message in chat:
    if message == 'agent':
        agent = True
        customer = False
    elif message == 'customer':
        agent = False
        customer = True
    elif agent:
        agent_list.append(message)
    elif customer:
        customer_list.append(message)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 6):

`index()` returns only the first index of the element so you'll need to accumulate the index of all occurrence by iterating over the list.

I would suggest to solve this using a simple for loop as:

```
agent_chat = []
customer_chat = []
chat_type = 'agent'
for chat in chats:
    if chat in ['agent', 'customer']:
        chat_type = chat
        continue
        
    if chat_type == 'agent':
        agent_chat.append(chat)
    else:
        customer_chat.append(chat)
```

Other approaches like list comprehension will require two iterations of the list.

Comment: One small suggestion: You might want to initialize `chat_type` with `chat_type = None`, so that everything that may come up in the list before anyone speaks (maybe status messages) is suppressed.

Comment: actually, I thought about it but then I'll have to tweak the else part to `elif` as well as the chats will go into the other list so I left it as is. If the list is valid, it will work perfectly, if not, we'll need to make appropriate adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I don't know this is the best one but I hope it helps

```
def chat_lists(chat):
agent_chat = []
customer_chat = []

user_flag = ""
for message in chat:
    if message == 'agent':
        user_flag = 'agent'
    elif  message == 'customer':
        user_flag = 'customer'
    else :
        if user_flag == 'agent':
            agent_chat.append(message)
        else:
            customer_chat.append(message)
return customer_chat, agent_chat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
chat = ['agent',
    'Hi',
    'how may I help you?',
    'customer',
    'I am facing issue with internet',
    'agent',
    'Can i know your name and mobile no.?'
    'customer',
    'john doe',
    '111111']
    agent = []
    customer = []
    
    for j in chat:
        if j=='agent':
            curr = 'agent'
            continue
        if j=='customer':
            curr = 'customer'
            continue
        if(curr=='agent'):
            agent.append(j)
        else:
            customer.append(j)
    
  print(agent)
  print(customer)
```

Comment: Why do you use `enumerate` here? `chat[i]` is the same as `j`. Two strong suggestions: Use meaningful names for your variables and drop the parentheses in your `if` conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will update my answer

Answer (score -1):

You can set up a while loop to parse through the messages, and set up a variable to act as a 'switch' for whether the agent or client is talking.

```py
# Get the current speaker (first speaker)
current_speaker = chat[0]

# Make the chat logs
agent_chat = []
customer_chat = []

# Iterate for the array
for message in chat:
    # If the current speaker is updated
    if message in ['agent', 'customer']:
        # Then update the speaker
        current_speaker = message
        # Skip to the next iteration
        continue

    # Add the message based 
    if current_speaker == 'agent':
        agent_chat.append(message)
    else:
        customer_chat.append(message)
```

Another note to keep in mind is that this whole system will bug out heavily if a customer or agent decides, for whatever reason, to type in the word 'agent' or 'customer'.

Comment: Did you see that the first agent has 2 replies, not one

Comment: the chats are not in even order, so this wont work.

Comment: @Xiddoc:, We can't use alternate indexes, agent/customer can have multiple lines.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I misread the format. Thought it was based by indexes. Give me a moment to edit my answer.

Comment: Hope this new answer helps you, I also added a final comment to warn you of a possible bug.